# Choosing the output of a pipe

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Given a pipe of the form `C1 | C2`, if `C2` takes more than one positional argument, is it possible to choose where the output of `C1` is going?

Consider the following example.

```
$ cat myscript 
#!/bin/bash
cat $1
cat $2
$ cat world.txt
World
$ echo "Hello" | ./myscript world.txt
World
Hello
```

I want the final output to be in correct order (Hello World) by altering only the right side of the pipeline.

Comment: `C1` output is not going into `$2`. Add `echo <$2>` to the script and you will see that. So the whole premise of your question is not correct.

Comment: The pipe connects the `stdout` of one program to the `stdin` of the other. It has nothing to do with the script arguments. What you see happening is that `$2` is actually empty in your example so the last `cat` reads from `stdin` which then comes from the pipe.

Comment: Also your script is just re-implementing `cat`. `cat` (concatenate) will read all files mentioned in its argument lists and output them one after another. Same as what your script is trying to do, but for more and less than 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
echo "Hello" | ./myscript /dev/stdin world.txt
```

So that standard input of ./myscript feeds into the first "cat"